# Travelling holiday and back to UK within a month before UK spouse visa expires

Tags: visas, uk, spouses, visa-expiration

I have a UK visa as the spouse visa of a British citizen and it is expiring in mid-September. I have plans to visit India exactly a month before the expiry date of this visa. Will it cause any issues at Immigration when I enter the UK a month before my visa expires?